# The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions

Tags: maintenance

I was updating my plugins, after one plug in update went a bit wrong my site was stuck in maintenance mode, the solution I found online was to delete the .maintanence file, which I did. But straight after that I got this message: The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions. How do I fix it now?..

Comment: did you tried removing the plugin (rename the plugin folder to plugin-name001)?

Answer (score 3):

You should troubleshoot your website for plugins.

As you are unable to access your WordPress admin area so please try to access your file manager in cPanel or access public_html directory via FTP.

Go to wp-content/ Directory them rename plugins/ directory to pluginsbackup/ now try to load your site. If this works that means you have problem with a plugin.

If problem is with plugin change back the directory name pluginsbackup/ to plugins/ Enter in plugin directory. Now rename each plugins directory by placing backup at end of that directory name.

Once you have changed all plugins directories names, start getting original directory names one by one and make sure you check the website if that’s still working after each plugin start working. As soon as you see which plugin is making problem just delete that plugin.

Source [The site is experiencing technical difficulties.](https://www.webfulcreations.com/the-site-is-experiencing-technical-difficulties/)

If you can't figure out what's wrong please turn on the wp debug mode so you can get details of error. Edit your wp-config.php from WordPress root using FTP. And

```
   >> Find
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

And replace with 
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Once you turn on the wp debug mode you are not able to see the details of issue, weather is related to some missing file or some plugin is producing the FATAL error you can track and apply appropriate fix. Thanks. Once problem is fixed don't forget to turn off the debug mode in wp-config.php

Answer (score 1):

Use your cPanel access and rename that specific plugin folder with any name. If you still don't get control back to your site then rename the plugin folder and then activate one plugin at a time to close down on the faulty plugin.

Comment: Thank you all! It is all sorted now. I tried to rename the plugin folder and it did nothing, but wgen I rnaimed the folder with the plugin which update went wrong it sorted the technical issue. Thank you!